# XSD validation issue with NIEM defined types

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to create a schema using NIEM elements and I'm having trouble getting it to validate.

My schema:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns="http://myservices.com/myservices/1.0" 
    targetNamespace="http://myservices.com/myservices/1.0" 
    xmlns:myservices="http://myservices.com/myservices/1.0" 
    xmlns:nc="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0"
    xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    xmlns:i="http://niem.gov/niem/appinfo/2.0"
    xmlns:s="http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:import schemaLocation="niem/niem-core/2.0/niem-core.xsd" namespace="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0"/>

      <xs:element name="MyServices" msdata:Prefix="myservices">
         <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                 <xs:element ref="nc:DocumentFileControlID" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="0" />
                 <xs:element ref="nc:DocumentCreationDate"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>

    </xs:schema>
```

And my xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <myservices:MyServices xmlns:nc="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0"
        xmlns:niem-xsd="http://niem.gov/niem/proxy/xsd/2.0" xmlns:myservices="http://myservices.com/myservices/1.0"
        xmlns:s="http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="MyServices.xsd">
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID>20130904-1114.453</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <nc:DocumentCreationDate>
            <nc:Date>2013-09-04</nc:Date>
        </nc:DocumentCreationDate>

    </myservices:MyServices>
```

The error I get when validating using SchemaFactory is:

```
Reason: cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'nc:DocumentCreationDate' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.
```

But in niem-core.xsd, the type is defined as nc:DateType. If I try to add that type to my element in my schema, I get an error saying I can't have a type in the element.

This is niem-core.xsd:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0" version="1" 
    xmlns:s="http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:nc="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0" xmlns:niem-xsd="http://niem.gov/niem/proxy/xsd/2.0" 
    xmlns:i="http://niem.gov/niem/appinfo/2.0">
      <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:appinfo>
          <i:ConformantIndicator>true</i:ConformantIndicator>
        </xsd:appinfo>
      </xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="../../proxy/xsd/2.0/xsd.xsd" namespace="http://niem.gov/niem/proxy/xsd/2.0"/>
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="../../appinfo/2.0/appinfo.xsd" namespace="http://niem.gov/niem/appinfo/2.0"/>
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="../../structures/2.0/structures.xsd" namespace="http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0"/>
      <xsd:complexType name="DateType">
        <xsd:annotation>
          <xsd:appinfo>
            <i:Base i:namespace="http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0" i:name="Object"/>
          </xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:complexContent>
          <xsd:extension base="s:ComplexObjectType"/>
        </xsd:complexContent>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:element name="DocumentCreationDate" type="nc:DateType"/>
      <xsd:element name="DocumentFileControlID" type="niem-xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
    </xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many references to additional imported XSDs that are not listed as part of the question.  This makes it hard to be sure what's wrong, but one issue is that the `xsi:schemaLocation` for your XML file should be namespace-URI pairs, not just a URI:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://myservices.com/myservices/1.0 MyServices.xsd"
```

If this isn't sufficient to resolve your problem, I'd suggest pruning the `xsd:imports` down and including any essential type definitions such as `ComplexObjectType` in your answer so that we have a complete set of definitions to use to help you resolve the validation problem.